# Как отследить появление кнопки и скрыть её?

Tags: javascript

На странице появляются 2 кнопки Да и Нет. Требуется скрыть кнопку НЕТ.

```
<div class="couple-flex-row couple-flex-center couple-relation-card--answers-1">
        
            <button class="js-couple-relation-card--answers--button couple-relation-card--answers--button" data-id="825085597"> Нет </button>
        
        <button class="js-couple-relation-card--answers--button couple-relation-card--answers--button" data-id="2820972327">  Да  </button>        
</div>
```

Сделал код, который добавляет id к кнопке НЕТ и потом скрываю с помощью display:none. Но как оказалось мой код работает, только когда кнопка НЕТ находится сверху как в приведённом HTML - коде. Как только кнопка НЕТ внизу, она не скрывается, т.к id не добавляется. Как удалить кнопку НЕТ в раз и навсегда?

```
new MutationObserver( Mutations => { for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
const buttonNo = document.querySelector(".couple-relation-card--answers--button");
  
    for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
      if (buttonNo.matches(".couple-relation-card--answers--button") && buttonNo.innerText === "Нет") buttonNo.id = "btnno";
      else {
        let NodeBtn = Node.querySelector(".couple-relation-card--answers--button");
        if (NodeBtn) buttonNo.id = "btnno";
      }}}
  }).observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Пробовал так, но тоже самое, не помогло

```
new MutationObserver( Mutations => {
 const buttonNo = document.querySelector(".couple-relation-card--answers--button");  
      for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
        for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
          if (buttonNo.matches(".couple-relation-card--answers--button") && buttonNo.innerText === "Нет") buttonNo.id = "btnno";
          else {
            let BtnNoCouple = Node.querySelectorAll(".couple-relation-card--answers--button");
            if ( (buttonNo.innerText === "Нет") && BtnNoCouple.length > 0) {
              BtnNoCouple.forEach(item => {
               item.id = "btnno";
              });
            }}}}
    }).observe( document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

И так попробовал

```
new MutationObserver( Mutations => {
 const buttonNo = document.querySelector(".couple-relation-card--answers--button");  
      for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
        for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
          if (buttonNo.matches(".couple-relation-card--answers--button") && buttonNo.innerText === "Нет") buttonNo.id = "btnno";
          else {
            let BtnNoCouple = Node.querySelectorAll(".couple-relation-card--answers--button");
    BtnNoCouple.forEach(item => {  if(buttonNo.innerText === "Нет"){   item.id = "btnno";  } });   
        
                  }}}
    }).observe( document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Comment: Попробуй у Node получить все кнопки Node.querySelectorAll(".couple-relation-card--answers--button"), Их перебрать и там где "Нет" добавить id, ну или добавить стиль elem.style.display='none'

Comment: Перебрать пробовал, тоже самое. Может неправильно, я же чайник.  а вот .style.display='none' точно тут не причём

Comment: Видимо ты меня не так понял. Строку с переменной buttonNo убери. if с matches убери, а вот это сделай так ```BtnNoCouple.forEach(item => {
            if(buttonNo.innerText === "Нет"){
              item.id = "btnno";
            }
               
              });```

Comment: Посмотри, правильно я тебя понял? Если да, то это не помогло.

Comment: Нет, сейчас добавлю свой код в ответы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new MutationObserver(Mutations => {
    for (let Mutation of Mutations) {

        for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) {
            if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
                  
                const buttons = Node.querySelectorAll('.js-couple-relation-card--answers--button'); //Если возникнут проблемы с другими кнопками делай с комбинаторами
                buttons.forEach((elem) => {
                    if (/(Н|н)(Е|е)(Т|т)/.test(elem.innerText)) { // регулярное выражение для поиска слова "нет" в тексте
                        // elem.setAttribute('style', 'display:none !important')
                        elem.id = 'nobtn'
                    }
                })

            }
        }
    }

}).observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Comment: Да, так работает как надо. Единственое почему-то не работает, когда страницу обновляешь.

Comment: При старте страницы видимо тоже нужно вызывать

Comment: Ещё-бы знать как это сделать

Comment: Радует, что работает, когда переходишь  на предыдущую страницу, а потом обратно с кнопками.